# Can't add a product to cart

Tags: magento2, cart, exception

in my store I have some configurable product and other simple product.

No problem until this morning. I can't add any product in my cart anymore. I don't know why, I have only this exception :

```
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getValue() on
> null in
> project/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Quote/Item/CartItemProcessor.php:86
> Stack trace: #0
> project/generated/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Model/Quote/Item/CartItemProcessor/Proxy.php(103):
> Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Quote\Item\CartItemProcessor->processOptions(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item))
> 1 project/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item/CartItemOptionsProcessor.php(84):
> Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Quote\Item\CartItemProcessor\Proxy->processOptions(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item))
> 2 project/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item/CartItemPersister.php(108):
> Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\CartItemOptionsProcessor->addProductOptions('configurable',
> Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Ite in
> project/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Quote/Item/CartItemProcessor.php
> on line 86
```

I didn't edit any of theses files.

Answer (score 1):

My fault.

I've created a product and then added it to my cart.

Then, I've added configuration to this product. And it's not possible to have the old simple product in the cart.

As magento call the cart, I called an impossible value of the old simple product.

So removing the old product from the cart did the trick.

Comment: please accept it as an answer

Comment: @KalyanChakravarthiV a bit of patience, you can accept your own answer after 2 days

Comment: you beat me to it ^^

Comment: Had the same issue. However, for me it was impossible to remove that product from a cart as a customer and I ended up having to remove some entries from the quote_item database table directly.